# How to only remove duplicate lines if they're immediately after each other in the file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Lets say I have the following file:

```
$ cat test.txt
a
-----
b
-----
-----
c
-----
-----
-----
d
-----
e
-----
-----
```

Now I want to remove all the `-----`, but only if they're repeating after each other. So the result should look like this:

```
a
-----
b
-----
c
-----
d
-----
e
-----
```

I tried `grep -Pvz -- "-----\n-----"`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's exactly what the `uniq` command is made for:

```
NAME
       uniq - report or omit repeated lines

SYNOPSIS
       uniq [OPTION]... [INPUT [OUTPUT]]

DESCRIPTION
       Filter adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT
       (or standard output).

       With no options, matching lines are merged to the first occurrence.
```

So

```
$ uniq test.txt 
a
-----
b
-----
c
-----
d
-----
e
-----
```

Alternatively, you can use this sed one-liner **69. Delete duplicate, consecutive lines from a file (emulates "uniq")** from [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part III: Selective Deletion of Certain Lines and Special Applications](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-three)

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' test.txt
```

which might be preferred if you want to edit `test.txt` in place (by adding the `-i` or `--in-place` option).

Answer (score 0):

just do `uniq filename.txt`
As the name states only unique lines are left and the repetitions are merged